# Endomorphism ring of $x \Bbbk\langle x,y \rangle + y \Bbbk\langle x,y \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

> Let $R = \Bbbk \langle x,y \rangle$, where $\Bbbk$ is a field. I want to determine $\underline{\text{End}}_R(xR + yR)$, the ring of (not necessarily degree-preserving) graded module homomorphisms of the right ideal $xR + yR$.

I know that we have an inclusion $R \hookrightarrow \underline{\text{End}}_R(xR + yR)$ given by $p \mapsto \phi_p$, where $\phi_p(q) = pq$, and I'm inclined to believe that this is actually an isomorphism, but I can't prove surjectivity. Is this an isomorphism, and if so, how should I go about proving it?

Comment: is $\Bbbk \langle x,y \rangle$ a strange notation for $\Bbbk [x,y]$ ?

Comment: @mercio I think we are here in a non-commutative world.

Comment: @user26857 : thanks, I'm not familiar with it and now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$xR\cap yR=\{0\}$, so your ideal is the direct sum of $xR$ and $yR$, both of which are isomorphic to $R$ as right ideals, so its endomorphism algebra is isomorphic to $M_2(R)$.

Comment: Thanks. Is an explicit isomorphism given by $\phi \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b  \\
c & d \end{array} \right)$, where $\phi(x) = ax + cy, \phi(y) = bx + dy$?

Comment: @Mark Yes, exactly.